# Changes to eclipse due to snap?

Tags: 18.04, eclipse, snap

It's a few weeks since I started eclipse but after trying to open it today, I get the 'no more handles' SWT error which I remember fixing before by setting SWT_FTK3-0.

Now I find that eclipse seems to be under snap which I am not familiar with. Furthermore there appear to be a `/snap/eclipse/40`, a `/snap/eclipse/29` and a `/snap/eclipse/current`. I think 40 and current are the latest eclipse.

I think I want to edit either the eclipse.ini in 40 or current to have the lines

```
--launcher.GTK_version
2
```

but I don't seem to be able to do it. Can anyone please suggest how I can recover my eclipse?

I am running the latest ubuntu 18.04 and a couple of days ago 'livepatch' made some changes

I have seen this error when I start Ubuntu in the default gnome and Wayland. If I select unity from the gear icon, then eclipse will stat OK. I'm fairly certain that I started eclipse and checked for updates less than 2 weeks ago, so I wonder what has changed to break, such that I can't fix it?

**UPDATE**

I have managed  to get eclipse started using an `eclipse.ini` in `/etc`. That file contains the reference to GTK version 2. I have done this with the command line from a terminal window

```
eclipse --launcher.ini /etc/eclipse.ini
```

However this produces the error

> The Eclipse executable launcher no longer supports running with GTK
>   +2.x Continuing using GTK+3.x.

This leaves me with the `"no more handles error"` and I can't run eclipse.

Comment: Please edit your question and post the ouput of the command `echo  $PATH`

Comment: For what it;s worth, I have:  echo $PATH
/home/nick/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games::/snap/bin:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/bin:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/db/bin:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/bin:/home/nick/scripts

Comment: You have three version of eclipse: 29, 40 and current. Is `current` a symlink? I verified your PATH and there was no reference about eclipse binary. Have you created any symlink in /usr/local/bin/ that tracks the version you are using? Please check.

Comment: Marked as solved, fix is shown in update 2

Comment: please post solution in answer place and revert your edit

Comment: Put the question back like it was and keep your nose out of where it has no business. You have hidden useful information